# Create an executable file to run the Angular build command in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, command-prompt

I've created a .cmd file that contains the following

```
Echo On
ng build --prod --output-path docs -- base-href https://blkx-darkreaper.github.io/
```

The intent is that when this file is executed from windows explorer it will simply open up a new cmd window and execute the build automatically. Currently though I'm getting an unknown exception but the window closes before I can see all the details. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Add a new line underneath it `@Pause`. You should be able to read your exception message, before pressing any key for the script to continue, or the window to close.

Comment: Is it not supposed to be `--base-href`? It's also worth mentioning that `ng` is really `ng.cmd`, so don't be lazy, and use its extension too. Without doing so you are relying upon the user not having modified their `%PATHEXT%`, or not having another file in the current directory with the same name and one of the extensions listed under `%PATHEXT%`. In addition to that, you'd need to ensure that the current directory of the running script was the same as the location of `ng.cmd`, or that the location of `ng.cmd` was listed somewhere within the value data for the `%Path%` environment variable.

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, thanks. Although the window still closed without user input

Comment: Use `@Call ng.cmd build ...` with the `@Pause` line if you want the batch file window to remain open until 'any key' has been pressed.